# How do I shorten the size of a TikZ XY system?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make an XY system with TikZ that has xmax=200, ymax=120, xmin=0 and ymin=0. The figure, though, is huge! How do I shorten the size of the figure?

Comment: Look up data visualization (page 757).

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you mean by XY system? And please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, the `datavisualization` library or the `pgfplots` package might be of interest. You can change the length of the unit vectors with `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.05cm, y=0.05cm]`, but if you're plotting functions or data, there are as mentioned better options.

Answer (score 1):

TikZ takes coordinates that do not carry an unit to be in centimeters. You can either give a unit to your max/min values or use `[xscale = .., yscale = ..]` or `[scale = {..,..}]` as an option to a surrounding scope. These options can be supplied to the `\tikzpicture` as well, but to my knowledge that is deprecated.

If you a visualising data, take a look at `\datavisualization` and its various scaling options, it offers "hardcoded" scaling, mapping min and max values to surrounding units (again centimeters per default) or automatic scaling that is usually sufficient.

Comment: I'm curious, where did you see that adding a `scale` option to a `tikzpicture` is deprecated? Is it stated in the manual somewhere?